# How to use cascade with ManyToMany relationship

Tags: hibernate

I am trying cascade with many to many relationship, I have two classes Employee and Meeting and they are mapped like below

```
Employee.java
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "EMPLOYEE_MEETING", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "MEETING_ID")})
    private List<Meeting> meetings = new ArrayList<>();

Meeting.java
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "meetings", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
```

with Insert its working fine but when I remove single entity like

```
Employee employee = entityManager.find(Employee.class, 1);
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.remove(employee);
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

its deleting all the meetings associated with that employees then its again deleting all the employees that are associated with tat meeting.

So I am confused over here how to use cascades with many to many relationship?

Comment: It is the expected behaviour, when you delete an Employee all Meetings associated with the Employee are deleted because of the cascade. When a Meeting is deleted all associated Employees are deleted because of cascade too.

Comment: You don't need to delete a Meeting when an Employee is deleted, because other employees are still associated to the Meeting. You can use something like "DELETE_ORPHAN" so that a Meeting will be deleted if all associated Employees are deleted.